# What's wrong with this XML with PIs (Processing Instructions)?

Tags: xml, xml-validation, processing-instruction

My XML file does not work correctly now, but worked earlier.

An online validator provided this error:

> Message : Invalid '[ "urlset"]' found.

I don't know what is wrong with this `urlset`.
Here is syntax:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <? foreach ($nizkochastotki AS $data) { ?>
    <url>
        <loc>https://<?=$host?><?=$data['url']?></loc>
        <lastmod><?=date('Y-m-d')?></lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
    <? }?>
</urlset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing a schema and documentation regarding allowed PIs (`<? ... ?>` Processing Instructions), we cannot completely "correct" your file, but we can show you what it would take to make it well-formed:

Note that a PI must have a target name the conforms to

```
[17] PITarget ::= Name - (('X' | 'x') ('M' | 'm') ('L' | 'l'))

[4]  NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
[4a] NameChar ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
[5]  Name ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*
```

that is, among other requirements, it must start with a letter or several of the listed characters.

Note also that a PI target must appear immediately after the `<?` – no whitespace may intercede:

```
[16] PI ::= '<?' PITarget (S (Char* - (Char* '?>' Char*)))? '?>'
```

So, if you remove the space ahead of `foreach`, and then add whatever PI targets are allowed by the processing application (`XXX` as a placeholder below), the following XML is now at least well-formed:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <?foreach ($nizkochastotki AS $data) { ?>
    <url>
        <loc>https://<?XXX =$host?><?XXX  =$data['url']?></loc>
        <lastmod><?XXX =date('Y-m-d')?></lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
    <?XXX }?>
</urlset>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to correctly implement this decision in php and html syntax.

Comment: Your question and its tagging said nothing about PHP or HTML.  This answers your question as asked.  Please accept if you found it to be helpful.  If you require further help regarding PHP or HTML, post a new question with a [mcve] illustrating the issue.  Thanks.